# Android com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider null reference issue

Tags: android, android-studio

In my application I am using Google play services so that I use compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` in gradle file. I get "com.google.android.gms.measurement is null" issue even if tried the below solution

I have added in application class with the following

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

and `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` and added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'` in project level - `build.gradle`
but still get `com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider null reference`

Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5122)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4725)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:159)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zzz(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1214)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1189)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4725) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4665) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:159) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You get fix for this?

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Do not use: `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`
Use only the parts of it that is necessary for your app.
For example I use for my app this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
```

And try to add at the end of your file this:
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: Where to add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'?

Comment: last line in your build.gradle file. nothing comes after

Comment: Now again, try not to use the whole play services. And like that you don't even need multidex, because your project will be a lot smaller. Also quicker build times

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Kindly let me know how to find relevant dependencies for the following.

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult; import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient; import com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.Info; import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException; import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;

Comment: and I get Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found. when add apply plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Then try this:
Leave compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'`
And leave the apply plugin: `'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end. This should work

Comment: @rosualin I am also facing the same issue, can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I solved this by updating the play store dependency version to 9.8.0.

This is the libraries I updated in my project:

```
implementation(group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services', version: '9.8.0')

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
```

Then in the manifest I added this to avoid the issue of exported attributed of android components restrictions for Android 31 and above:

```
<activity
            android:exported = "true"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerPreviewActivity">
        </activity>


        <receiver
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported = "true"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Hopeful this works for you. This is for a legacy code app.